# Why might a site perform better when the developer tools are open?

Tags: javascript, c#, web, kendo-ui, developer-tools

We have a site developed with a C# MVC back-end and KendoUI client-side. In the four major browsers we test (Chrome, Firefox, IE, Edge), we can get the site to lag and even go unresponsive. This problem, obviously, is worst on IE and Edge, but does replicate on Chrome and Firefox.

Our biggest issue in finding the culprit of this slowdown is that it will not reproduce if developer tools are open in any browser. So we are unable to debug the issue and find what's going wrong.

That leads us to think that the developer tools must have some setting we are unaware of that is preventing the bug. Any idea what that could be?

Comment: Make sure you remove/comment out all usage of  `console` for production purposes. Older versions of IE will actually crash when it runs into `console` calls when the console is not open.

Comment: @ScottMarcus, thanks for the suggestion. I removed all the console calls but the bug persists!

Comment: Do you have the cache disabled in the tools? Maybe try a separate monitoring tool like Fiddler? Kendo has a lot of potentially big scripts and css...

Comment: @SteveGreene I just tried this earlier today. I made sure it was disabled and was unable to replicate still. Thanks for the tip. I'll look into Fiddler.

I agree. Kendo is not my favorite, but it was not my choice to use it

Comment: We've had good luck with Kendo. Bit of a learning curve though.